# ¿Obtener datos de un JSON.parse array?

Tags: php, javascript, json

Estoy trabajando en JavaScript, una parte del código me hace una consulta en un archivo de PHP para obtener las propiedades de una persona, los cuales almaceno en una variable después de parsearlos con `JSON.parse(response)` luego al hacer un forEach me dice que no es un objeto, me da un error, ¿alguien podría ayudarme?

Código de JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/Ok/tasks/taskPropsCharge.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {pjName:PJNAME},
        success: function (response) {
            let props = JSON.parse(response);
            let plantilla = ``;
            props.forEach(local => {
                plantilla += `
                    <tr>
                        <td>Nombre</td>
                        <td class="price" id = "name">${props.NombreLocal}</td>
                    </tr>
                `
            });
            $('#props').html(plantilla);
        }
    });
```

Me da este error `Uncaught TypeError: props.forEach is not a function`

Actualización: Añado el código que se ejecuto en la parte del "taskPropsCharge".

```
<?php
    include("dbcon.php");
    session_start();

    IF(isset($_POST['pjName'])){
        $pjName = $_POST['pjName'];

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pcu_locales WHERE Propietario = '$pjName'");
        $getrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
        IF($getrows != 0){
            $datos = mysql_fetch_array($query);
            $jsonstring = json_encode($datos);
            echo $jsonstring;
        } else {
            echo "No hay datos";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Utiliza un console.log(props); para verificar que valor tiene props despues de ser parseado o convertido a JSON

Comment: @AnibalOspina https://i.ibb.co/fHXHYxv/image.png Eso es lo que me arroja.

Comment: @CarlosAlbertoMarrufo Te dice que props.forEach() is not a function porque props no es un array, sino un objeto (segun la imagen que pasaste)
Podrias subir el codigo del backend?

Comment: Lo que puedo visualizar es que probablemente en tu archivo PHP estas codificando a JSON un array que no es asociativo. Como dice @Ale si subes tu backend tendriamos mas información para ayudarte

Comment: Ahí lo he añadido. Estoy comprobando y tienen razón, pero, ¿se solucionaría enviando los datos dependiendo si obtiene un array o más de uno, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actualización:

Rebuscando un poquito en el código, me di cuenta que estaba pasando el resultado de la consulta directamente (cómo se ve en la pregunta), en lugar de crear el objeto en el archivo PHP de esta manera.

```
$pjName = $_POST['pjName'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pcu_locales WHERE Propietario = '$pjName' AND TipoLocal = 1");

$json = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $json[] = array(
    'NombreLocal' => $row['NombreLocal'],
    'GPS' => $row['GPS'],
    'Calle' => $row['Calle']
    );
}
$jsonstring = json_encode($json);
echo $jsonstring;
```

De esta manera, como estaba trabajando anteriormente me funciona perfectamente.